# Why does adding a data type as constraint to type declaration result in matching error instead of a more correct error?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Or, putting in other terms, is there a case to add a constraint like described below?

**Working code**, with minimal type declaration for function *f*:

```
data ZeroPositive = Zero | Positive Int deriving Show
f :: [Int] -> [ZeroPositive]
f [] = []
f (0:xs) = Zero:(f xs)
f (x:xs) = (Positive x):(f xs)
main = putStrLn . show $ f [0,2]
```

result:

```
[Zero,Positive 2]
```

**Broken code** with useless constraint *ZeroPositive*:

```
data ZeroPositive = Zero | Positive Int deriving Show
f :: ZeroPositive => [Int] -> [ZeroPositive]
f [] = []
f (0:xs) = Zero:(f xs)
f (x:xs) = (Positive x):(f xs)
main = putStrLn . show $ f [0,2]
```

result:

```
  99.hs:3:7:
  Couldn't match expected type `ZeroPositive' with actual type `[t0]'
  In the pattern: []
  In an equation for `f': f [] = []

  99.hs:3:12:
  Couldn't match expected type `[Int] -> [ZeroPositive]'
          with actual type `[a0]'
  In the expression: []
  In an equation for `f': f [] = []

  ...

  99.hs:6:32:
  Couldn't match expected type `ZeroPositive' with actual type `[t0]'
  In the first argument of `f', namely `[0, 2]'
  In the second argument of `($)', namely `f [0, 2]'
  In the expression: putStrLn . show $ f [0, 2]
```

Comment: What Haskell implementation are you using (including version number)? Does your code really say exactly `f :: ZeroPositive => [Int] -> [ZeroPositive]`? I'd expect that to give a kind error, and it does on my computer.

Comment: Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.6.3, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.6.3

Comment: 7.6.3 is essentially obsolete. 7.8.4 is still fairly widely used. The most recent release was 7.10.2; there may or may not be a 7.10.3 at some point to fix a few more bugs, and 8.0 is scheduled for February.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *should* be an error because `ZeroPositive` is a data type, not a class, so is not allowed as a constraint.

However the strange error message you are getting, is because you are using an old GHC version that had [a bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8863) (<s>GHC 7.4 if I recall correctly</s>GHC 7.6, the one which got the `ConstraintKinds` extension generally working and therefore made `=>` and `->` allowed in more of the same places in the syntax) that made it treat `=>` as `->` if you put an actual data type instead of constraint to the left of it.

Comment: I was a bit confused because I found a webpage noting that 7.4 was the version that introduced the extension.  However I now remember reading that it was so broken that it was only at 7.6 that they got fixed enough that people could start *using* it. I haven't managed to find the actual GHC bug report for the `=>` vs. `->` confusion (impossible to Google those).

Comment: Interesting reason for the error message, thanks. I will try to find a better way to keep my ghc up to date.

Comment: And I finally found the bug ticket.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand the error you're getting; Ørjan Johansen's answer gives a plausible explanation. The real problem is this: any time a type signature indicates `a => b`, `a` is expected to be a *constraint*. In standard Haskell, that means that `a` looks like `C t`, where `C` is the name of a class and `t` is a type variable. In Glasgow Haskell, constraints can be a great deal richer. In any case, however, data and constraint are entirely different sorts of things (they have different types, in a general sense), so you simply can't use a datatype as a context.

Comment: Thanks, I still mix some concepts sometimes. Is Haskell Platform recommended or there are other better options?

Comment: @B.Zen, opinions vary widely, and the "what's the best way to get Haskell" question is a matter of active discussion and development. A lot of people seem to like `stack` for work that doesn't require bleeding-edge libraries. Others prefer to go with a traditional `cabal-install` approach with lots of sandboxes (an approach that is becoming much more manageable than it used to be). I can't make any particular recommendations.